# fetch Prototype.json() corrupts/changes body data

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I've been banging my head for a week already. This is impossible and yet it happens (javascript, I know):

I am using fetch to get data from server as follows:

```
fetch(this.props.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                class: 'property',
                action: 'view', 
                objectId: this.props.element.id,
                token: this.props.token,
            }),
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);})
```

Now, testing with Postman gets me the correct result:

```
"units": [
            {
                "amount_due": 22.0,
                "id": 31,
                "floor": 5,
                "common_percentage": 0.012223,
                "building": {} 
            },
            {
                "amount_due": 16.0,
                "id": 33,
                "floor": 5,
                "common_percentage": 0.012143223,
                "building": {} 
            }
         ]
```

However, the console logs both units with an id of 33.

Checked the backend 100 times and it returns correct data. Postman confirms it. Also tried parsing the response with .text() instead of .json() and .text() returns the correct data. This corruption happens with .json() only. Am I going crazy or have I found a bug (or peculiarity) with .json() method?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Thanks to @ChrisG I found out my code is somehow corrupting the data. It all happens after this.setState is called:

```
let completedProjects = json.property.projects.filter((project) => project.finish_date);
                    let completedJobs = json.property.jobs.filter((job) => job.complete.filter((completion) => completion.id == this.props.user.id).length > 0 && !job.on_hold && !job.deleted);
                    let timeline = [{title: <Trans>heading.property.added</Trans>, createdAt: <Moment locale={this.props.i18n.language} format="ll">{json.date_created}</Moment>, comment: <Trans>description.property.added</Trans>, icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home" />, sortCriterion: this.props.element.date_created }];
                    let inspections = this.state.inspections; 
                    json.inspections.map((inspection)=>{
                        inspections.push({description: inspection.type.description, date: <Moment format="ll">{inspection.instance.date_performed}</Moment>, name: inspection.type.name, interval: inspection.type.interval, typeId: inspection.type.id, });
                    });
                    completedProjects.map((project) => {
                        timeline.push({title: <Trans>heading.project.completed</Trans>, createdAt: <Moment format="ll">{project.finish_date}</Moment>, comment: project.name, icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="project-diagram" />, sortCriterion: project.finish_date, iconColor: '#007bff' });
                    });
                    completedJobs.map((job) => {
                        timeline.push({title: <Trans>heading.job.finished</Trans>, createdAt: <Moment format="ll">{job.finish_date}</Moment>, comment: job.name, icon: <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check" />, sortCriterion: job.finish_date, iconColor: '#007bff' });
                    });
                    timeline.sort((a, b) => a.sortCriterion < b.sortCriterion);
                    this.setState({
                        element: json.property,
                        activeJobs: json.property.jobs.filter((job) => job.complete.filter((completion) => completion.id == this.props.user.id).length == 0 && !job.on_hold && !job.deleted),
                        completedJobs: completedJobs,
                        remainingJobs: json.property.jobs.filter((job) => job.on_hold || job.deleted),
                        // activeProjects: json.property.projects.filter((project) => !project.finish_date),
                        activeProjects: json.property.projects,
                        completedProjects: completedProjects,
                        collapse: true,
                        timeline: timeline,
                    });
```

One clarification: the "units" part (the one that gets corrupted) is a property of the 'property' object. Now that I am writing this, might it be possible 'property' is a some kind of reserved word and it messes things?

EDIT 2:

Pinned the problem down to this:

```
this.setState({element: json.property})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The very first thing you should do is `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` to avoid the live console output being changed before you look at it.

Comment: @ChrisG - ok, this returns the correct data. What do you think this means? My issue is that I use the ids as react mapping keys (and they are the wrong ones).

Comment: It means `.json()` works as it should. You have a bug in your own React code most likely. Create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have some code below that apparently corrupts the data. Thanks. Do you want to post an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Not sure what to post as answer tbh. The question as-is just lost all relevance and won't help anybody else.

Comment: I will answer it myself when I find the exact piece of code that corrupts the data. The corrupts/changes data part of the question might help someone googling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turned out the problem lies within this.setState() function, as it somehow corrupts the data. So, fetch response.proptotype.json() functions as expected. I am opening a new issue to track the real problem. Thanks @ChrisG for the directions.